# Keep only a subtree of the DOM tree

Tags: jquery, dom

On BBC articles, such as [this one](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-15710473), there is a DOM element with class `story-body`, deep in the DOM chain.

I want to hide all DOM element "outside" of this (unique) DOM element. The problem is that I can't just do

```
$('*').hide();
$('.story-body');
```

because I need to make sure to keep the parents, grand-parents, etc. of `story-body`. I also can't do

```
$('*').hide();

var current = $('.story-body').show();
while(current = current.parent()) {
   current.show();
}
```

because that would simply show everything.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hide everything, then show  `.story-body`, its chain of ancestors, and all of its descendants:

```
$("body *").hide();               // Hide all
var sb = $(".story-body").show(); // Find and show story-body
sb.parents().show();              // ...and its parents
sb.find("*").show();              // ...and its contents
```

Or as a two-liner if you like to super-compact things:

```
$("body *").hide();
$(".story-body").show().parents().show().end().find("*").show();
```

But I wouldn't count on the effect of hiding all of those other elements. Although when I tried it on that story, it worked fine.

Here's a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) for it, copy the `javascript:` line below and paste it in as the target of a bookmark, then navigate to a BBC News page and click the bookmark:

`javascript:(function(){(function(){var d=document,s=d.createElement("script"),st=new Date();s.src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js";d.body.appendChild(s);after();function after(){var $,sb;if(typeof jQuery!=="function"){if(new Date()-st<5000){setTimeout(after,100);}return;}$=jQuery.noConflict();$("body *").hide();sb=$(".story-body").show();sb.parents().show();sb.find("*").show();}})();})();`

Source:

```
(function() {
    // Load jQuery
    var d = document,
        s = document.createElement("script"),
        st = new Date();
    s.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js";
    d.body.appendChild(s);

    // Wait for it to load
    after();
    function after() {
        var $, sb;
        if (typeof jQuery !== "function") {
            // Not loaded yet
            if (new Date() - st < 5000) { // Give up after 5 seconds
                // Try again in 100ms
                setTimeout(after, 100);
            }
            return;
        }

        // Minimize impact
        $ = jQuery.noConflict();

        // Do the work
        $("body *").hide();
        sb = $(".story-body").show();
        sb.parents().show();
        sb.find("*").show();
    }
})();
```

Seems to work just fine on the four or five stories I tried.

Comment: Thanks for this. I get the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'write' of undefined" (jquery line 8931) Any ideas?

Comment: @Randomblue: No, sorry. The bookmarklet works, though (just triple-checked, actually copying the text from the answer above and such), so it must be something different between your code and the bookmarklet's code.

Comment: I'm writing a Google Chrome extension... I have no idea where the problem is coming from. The bookmarklet does indeed work fine.

Comment: @Randomblue: Weird! Which jQuery file are you using? (So I know what line 8931 is...)

Answer (score 1):

You could detach the story, remove everything else, then reinsert the story:

```
 var stories = $('.story-body');
 stories.detach();
 $(document.body).children().remove();
 stories.appendTo(document.body);
```

Comment: Not a bad thought, but it blows up the CSS being applied to the story area via structural selectors.